# Web - How to get user location after agreeing to share location?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, location, mapbox

When I call this after the page loads:

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options)` it throws the error: 
**[Violation] Only request geolocation information in response to a user gesture.**

I am using Chrome v65 on Mac.  I need to share the user's location when the page loads.  This is for users who have already agreed to share their location.

---

If I simulate the location in Chrome's Web Console, it's able to reliably always get the location via either getCurrentPosition or watchposition.  I've noticed different wifi connections being more reliably providing that information too.  Can anyone add any insight in regards to that?

Answer (score 2):

The violation simply explains what happens: the invoking of **getCurrentPosition** is, due to security reason, supposed to be triggered by a user's intentions such as clicking a button to get his current location. So the request to get geolocation information on page load without a user gesture will be blocked by Chrome.

Refer to the following resource for [more information](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/geolocation-on-load)

> Users are mistrustful of or confused by pages that automatically request their location on page load. Rather than automatically requesting a user's location on page load, tie the request to a user's gesture, such as a tapping a "Find Stores Near Me" button. Make sure that the gesture clearly and explicitly expresses the need for the user's location.